# Error when testing PUT/POST methods of $resource using $httpBackend

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, post, httpbackend, http-options-method

I am having an issue where I am trying to test a service that has been set up using $resource, and has various methods GET, PUT, POST.

I am using $httpBackend in my tests, and it works fine when testing the GET requests but fails on the PUT/POST - I think it may be due to it sending an OPTIONS request first.

Strangely if I change the factory to use $http.post() instead of using $resource, the test passes fine.

Does anyone know a way around this? Can I turn off the OPTIONS request? Or something...?

Thanks!

**service**

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('Reports', function ($resource, ApiConfig) {
        return $resource(ApiConfig.urlBase + "/protected/HttpResource/:id",{},{
        update: {method: 'PUT'},
        get: {method: 'GET',isArray: true},
        search: {method: 'GET',isArray: false},
        save: {method: 'POST'}
    });
});
```

The ApiConfig.urlBase resolves to http://localhost:8080/... in the tests

**test file**

```
describe("Reports", function() {

beforeEach(module("myApp"));

beforeEach(inject(function(_Reports_, _$httpBackend_, _ApiConfig_) {
    Reports = _Reports_;
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    ApiConfig = _ApiConfig_;
}));

afterEach(function() {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
});

describe("save method", function() {

    var report = {name: "TestReport", type: "HttpResource"};

    beforeEach(function() {
        url = ApiConfig.urlBase + "/protected/HttpResource/";
        $httpBackend.when("POST", url).respond();
    });

    it("should make POST request when save method called", function() {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST(url);
        Reports.save(report);
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I managed to get this working and it was nothing to do with OPTIONS, just to do with the URL I was checking.

$resource is set up by default to automatically strip trailing slashes - you can turn this off (see the Angular docs for $resource) or I just changed my URL in the test class and removed the last "/".

```
    beforeEach(function() {
        url = ApiConfig.urlBase + "/protected/HttpResource";
        $httpBackend.when("POST", url).respond();
    });
```

My PUT request used the same URL as above, that confused me for a while as I was expecting the id I was passing through to be used in the URL.

Maybe this helps someone else :)